# Probability of a 6-digit number with at most three digits repeated?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability

What is the probability that a 6 digit number selected at random contains at most three digits repeated?

I'm new to probability, and try as I might, I cannot solve this. Any help will be appreciated.

P.S. first digit cannot be zero

Comment: Is it even possible that a 6 digits number contains four repeated digits?

Comment: Is the first digit allowed to be zero?

Comment: @MichaelBehrend no

Comment: @ajotatxe 999999

Comment: "Is it even possible that a 6 digits number contains four repeated digits?"  Uh... why the heck not?  $131151$?

Comment: @fleablood in your number there is only one digit repeated, not four.

Comment: It seems @ajotatxe has a valid point hmm

Comment: @ajotatxe the question is framed exactly like this in my book, but the author meant to say that a single digit is repeated n number of times.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the author meant it as Arka Seth and I interpreted it but you are correct.  It is poorly stated.

Comment: @ArkaSeth see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803760/how-many-6-digit-numbers-are-possible-with-no-digit-appearing-more-than-thrice?rq=1

Comment: @rsadhvika thank you. I couldn't find the question before asking mine.